# Create sanity for GIT clone

Tags: git

I want to create a Jenkins pipeline which runs GIT clone sanity every 5 minutes. how can I catch error/issue if the GIT clone command is not working/fails or passed?

Comment: Check the exit status of `git clone`?

Comment: Is this the right syntax: `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket:XXX/XX/git_test.git if [ "$status" == "0" ]; then X else Y` ?

Comment: "it is based on can I based on the answer from here: link: In short, no." This confusing, even more, you talk to yourself.

Comment: Tnx :) I deleted that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is

```
if command; then
    # Every went OK
else
    # Something failed
fi
```

and it works for `git`:

```
if git clone ...; then
    # The repo was cloned correctly
else
    # Something failed
fi
```

The first branch is only taken if the `git clone` command exits with a status of 0, indicating success; any other exit status is considered failure, and causes the second branch to be taken.

Comment: so `if git clone` already covers all the return codes?

Comment: Yes, or rather, it looks for success: an exit code of 0 indicates success, so the first branch of the `if` is taken, anything else indicates failure, so the second branch of the `if` is taken.

Comment: and if I want to ignore error codes 127 and 128?

Comment: Why do you want to ignore those?

Comment: I want to separate between connection issues other issues (127 and 128 are for their specific purposes: command not found, errors already reported)

Answer (score 1):

With a non-existing file `a` and `cat` instead if `git` it amounts to something like:

```
]# e=$(cat a 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
]# echo ret=$? out=\"$e\"
ret=1 out="cat: a: No such file or directory"
```

Now I have the command's *output*, which is cat's stdout replaced by stderr, as "result" value. The return code comes for free as `$?`.

For comparison a successful `cat`:

```
]# e=$(cat atext 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
]# echo ret=$? out=\"$e\"
ret=0 out=""
```

-> Success with redirecting to null, empty error msg.

```
]# e=$(cat atext)
]# echo ret=$? out=\"$e\"
ret=0 out="First line of a"
```

-> Success, so "$e" holds data.

---

```
]# e=$(cat xxx 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
]# echo ret=$? out=\"$e\"
ret=1 out="cat: xxx: Is a directory"
```

-> Message is detailed, but exit code stays at unity.

### Yes I have a dir `xxx`: `git clone .git xxx` has just made it for me when I tried to provoke a specific error.

(So I switched to `cat`)

```
]# e=$(cat -M 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
]# echo ret=$? out=\"$e\"
ret=1 out="cat: invalid option -- 'M' Try 'cat --help' for more information."
]#
```

Still ret=1.

---

The link in comment shows some complaints about missing *specific* error codes for git. I think this is a double misunderstanding because the (porcelain) git commands are made for interactive use, and the (bash) shell has it's own concept about in- and output.

In my example, I should not complain about cat's uniform error code "1", or try to catch and parse the message in a *complex script* (which is the opposite of a *simple program*). I should check before if everything is ready and tell the user if necessary (error or warning).

I wonder what kind of error codes you get from `git clone`. The man pages of git are very silent on return codes. Just like vi's for example. Very unlike `mount`, whose "codes can be ORed".

---

Given a "unsafe" command `git clone $d` I can add the error code to the message, together with the source. This is an interactive one-liner:

```
]# d='xxx'; git clone $d || echo "g. cl. failed with $?"
fatal: destination path 'xxx' already exists and is not an empty directory.
g. cl. failed with 128
```

As a script, this is not so obvious; I would do it like:

```
]# . gc.sh 
fatal: destination path 'xxx' already exists and is not an empty directory.
g. cl. failed with 128
```

With `cat gc.sh`:

```
d='xxx'
git clone $d; ret=$?  
if (( $ret > 0 )) 
   then echo "g. cl. failed with $ret"
fi
```

Otherwise `$?` does not stay fresh enough. And the test on true/false is also explicit.